# Frequency of letters in text file. Small output issue

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So this method is supposed to read a text file and output the frequency of each letter. The text file reads:

- aaaa
- bbb
- cc

So my output should be:

- a = 4
- b = 3
- c = 2

Unfortunately, my output is:

- a = 4
- a = 4
- b = 3
- a = 4
- b = 3
- c = 2

Does anyone know why?

I tried modifying the loops but still haven't resolved this.

```
public void getFreq() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {

    File file = new File("/Users/guestaccount/IdeaProjects/Project3/src/sample/testFile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();
    String line;

    while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
            for (char c : chars) {
                if (hash.containsKey(c)){
                    hash.put(c, hash.get(c)+1);
                }else{
                    hash.put(c,1);
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry entry : hash.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrisvin Jem gave you the code to change because your `for` loop was in your `while` loop when reading from the `File`.

> Does anyone know why?

**As your question states, I'm going to explain why it gave you that output.**

**Reason:** The reason that it gave you the output of `a=4, a=4, b=3, a=4, b=3, c=3` is because your `for` loop was in your `while` loop meaning that each time that the `BufferedReader` read a new line, you iterated through the `HashMap` and printed its contents.

**Example:** When the `BufferedReader` reads the second line of the file, the `HashMap hash` already has the key, value pair for `a` and now, it just got the value for `b`. As a result, in addition to having already printed the value for `a` when reading the first line, it also prints the current contents of the `HashMap`, including the redundant `a`. The same thing happens for the third line of the file.

**Solution:** By moving the `for` loop out of the `while` loop, you only print the results **after** the `HashMap` has all its values, and **not while** the `HashMap` is still getting the values.

```
for (Map.Entry entry : hash.entrySet())
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
```

I hope this answer was able to explain **why you were getting that specific output**.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the printing loop outside of the reading loop.

```
public void getFreq() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {

    File file = new File("/Users/guestaccount/IdeaProjects/Project3/src/sample/testFile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();
    String line;

    while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
            for (char c : chars) {
                if (hash.containsKey(c)){
                    hash.put(c, hash.get(c)+1);
                }else{
                    hash.put(c,1);
                }
            }
    }
    for (Map.Entry entry : hash.entrySet()){
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```